# Lines for chart using unity UI

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, charts

I’m having a problem and and wonder if anyone can help.
I need to replicate a line chart using UI Toolkit and the standard UGUI to compare pros and cons.
I created dots for my UGUI chart and now I need to connect the dots between them using an image.
I used the image as a connection between the two dots and then I rotated the image and make it long equals to the distance between the relative points.
However, I’m encountering the following problems:

1. Only the first connection is rotated in the correct way.
2. All the connections have a positive angle that never gets rotated in the opposite angle
3. The connections are translated on the X axis and not in the center of the two dots.

This is the code I’m using:
This part of the code gets the list with the stored dots and creates dots where the values are.
then I loop between the first and second dot to create an image and align to them

`

```
private void ShowGraph(List<int> valueList)
{
    float graphHeight = _graphContainer.sizeDelta.y;
    //max of our value for the y axis
    float yMaximum = 100f;
    //distance between each circle in graph
    float xSize = 50f;

    GameObject lastCircleGameObject = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < valueList.Count; i++)
    {
        float xPosition = xSize + i * xSize;
        //in this case normalized the value, so if is 0 not goes really in 0
        float yPosition = valueList[i] / yMaximum * graphHeight;
        GameObject circleGameObject = CreateCircle(new Vector2(xPosition, yPosition));
        if (lastCircleGameObject != null)
        {
             CreateDotConnection(lastCircleGameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition,
                         circleGameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition);
         }

         lastCircleGameObject = circleGameObject;
     }
}
```

`

In this part of code I create the connection

```
private void CreateDotConnection(Vector2 dotPositionA, Vector2 dotPositionB)
{
      GameObject go = new GameObject("dotConnection", typeof(Image));
      go.transform.SetParent(_graphContainer, false);
      go.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color(1, 1, 1, .5f);
      RectTransform rectTransform = go.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
            
      float distance = Vector2.Distance(dotPositionB, dotPositionA);
            
      rectTransform.anchorMin = new Vector2(0, 0);
      rectTransform.anchorMax = new Vector2(0, 0);
      rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(distance, 3);
      rectTransform.anchoredPosition = dotPositionA;

      float angle = Vector2.Angle(dotPositionB,dotPositionA ) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
      rectTransform.Rotate(new Vector3(0,0,angle));
            
      float centerX = (dotPositionB.x + dotPositionA.x) / 2;
      float centerY = (dotPositionB.y + dotPositionA.y) / 2;

      Vector2 centerPos = new Vector2(centerX,centerY);
      rectTransform.transform.position = centerPos;

}
```